# WPF data annotations/validation strange behaviour

Tags: wpf

I have a class with the following property, which is bound to a textbox on my view:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a value!")]
[Range(0, 255, ErrorMessage = "Must be 0-255")]
public byte Register0Value
{
    ...etc...
```

When I run the app and empty the textbox, it displays the error message "Input string was not in a correct format", rather than the message in the Required attribute.
Similarly if I enter a value such as "999", I get the error message "Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte".

Is this expected behaviour or am I missing something? I can get the desired behaviour by changing my property to a nullable int, but I shouldn't have to do this should I?

Thanks in advance

Andrew

Comment: it may sound strange, but can you try changing the order of the validation attributes.. i am suspecting that first error message is overridden by the second message.. just try Range first and required as next.

Comment: @bathineni sorry, that made no difference.

Comment: I now realise why this is happening - WPF can't convert a string (textbox) to a byte (viewmodel property). The validation error messages are presumably a result of exceptions being raised somewhere in the WPF databinding framework. So my next question - is there a way to intercept these exceptions and output a more meaningful validation message?

Comment: i suggest you to create new custom validation attribute. which  is much simple that intercepting error messages